# Is it correct to say "don't touch the food, the worship is not done yet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

So, this is a part of Asian culture.

[image]

As shown in the above picture, a woman "**sets the holy table for God**" (I'm not sure it's correct to say it) (ie, put some bowls of food, chopstics, etc on the holy table **for God to eat**).

She then burns some sticks of incense.

There is a container for holding incense sticks. To make it possible, some sand or earth is put inside a container.

The woman will poke the wooden end of the burning incense stick **into** the sand.

Bur most people don't say "*put the stick *into* the sand*". I think they will say "*put the stick **in** the container*" (but I am not sure we use "**on**" or "**in**" in this case).

Then she will "**place her palms together**" as the above picture (not sure it is correct to say like that)

Then she will bow down a few times to "**ask God for help**" or "**pray to God for help**" or "**worship God for help**" (I am not sure it is correct to say it).

After that, the woman may leave but noone is allowed to touch the food on the holy table until all the "**incense sticks are burnt up**" (I am not sure it is correct to say it) (ie, the incense stick is like a cigarette, when you burn a cigarette it will burn until it reaches its butt, likewise the incense part will burn up until it reaches the wooden part)

While the incense sticks are still in its burning-up process, is it correct to say to a child "**don't touch the food, the worship is not done yet**" or "**don't touch the food, the praying is not done yet**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult for an English speaker on the other side of the world to know what's 'correct' when describing a completely different culture, but I guess you could say "The ceremony isn't over yet".

We would speak of something upright like a candle or an incense stick as being burnt *down* rather than *up*.

*Worship* refers to giving honour and praise to God; we would use *pray* when asking for something.

Comment: "Ceremony" could be a big word. We do this almost every week and it doesn't have to be a lot of food being put on the holy table. My mom may put a bunch of bananas on the table and prays. Do we have a smaller word for it, like "the worship is not over"?

Comment: A ceremony can be large or small, but if you prefer to call it 'worship', that's fine.

Comment: More people used to "say grace" before meals when I was a kid.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but from Tom's description this seems to be something rather different. Grace is thanking God for the food, not offering it.